# Python: Unable to convert wav to flac

Tags: python, python-3.x, wav, file-conversion, flac

I want to convert an audio(.wav) file to text. I found this [Repo](https://github.com/pranavrc/audio-transcribe) by search but it was written in Python 2.x. I converted the syntax to 3.x

```
 #!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
import os
import json
import subprocess as sp

url = "https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?xjerr=1&client=chromium&lang=en-US"
fileName = str(sys.argv[1])
fileExtension = os.path.splitext(fileName)[1]
converted = False

if fileExtension != ".flac":
    fnull = open(os.devnull, 'w')
    sp.call("pacpl --overwrite -t flac " + fileName, shell = True, stdout = fnull, stderr = fnull)
    fnull.close()
    fileName = os.path.splitext(fileName)[0] + '.flac'
    converted = True

try:
    binary_audio = open(fileName, 'rb')
except:
    print("Failed to get binary data.")

size_of_audio = os.path.getsize(fileName)

if converted:
    os.remove(fileName)

request = urllib.request.Request(url)
request.add_header('Content-type','audio/x-flac; rate=16000')
request.add_header('Content-length', str(size_of_audio))
request.add_data(binary_audio)

try:
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
except urllib.error.URLError as e:
    print("Unable to connect")
except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
    print("Oops, bad request")

content = response.read()

data = json.loads(content)

print(data["hypotheses"][0]["utterance"])
```

but when I run the script I get this error:

```
$ python speech.py /Users/amin/AnacondaProjects/audio-transcribe/softkitty.wav
```

> Failed to get binary data. Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "speech.py", line 26, in 
>       size_of_audio = os.path.getsize(fileName)   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/genericpath.py", line 50, in getsize
>       return os.stat(filename).st_size FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   '/Users/amin/AnacondaProjects/audio-transcribe/softkitty.flac'

Comment: Well, an error says there is no file at `/Users/amin/AnacondaProjects/audio-transcribe/softkitty.flac`. What else do you need to know to fix that?

Comment: Why my file did not convert to .flac?

Comment: You can try to debug an application, put a breakpoint before line 26 and run `os.path.getsize(fileName)` with different parameters in console to figure it out..